# Modelling a type hierarchy for a DSL in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor, default-value

I am trying to model a DSL in Scala. (I am very new to Scala so I might be missing something trivial, in which case apologies).
The DSL supports a very simple type system, where entities called 'Terms' can have a type, which either extends `Object` by default, or can extend other types, which in their own right eventually extend another type or `Object`.

I am trying to model this type hierarchy in Scala using a case class:

```
case class TermType(name: String, superType: TermType)
```

However, I want to be able to support a 'default' case (the one where the type just extends 'Object'), without having to specify the super type, so something of the sort:

```
//the following does not work, just illustrating what I want to achieve
case class TermType(name: String, superType: TermType = new TermType("Object", ???))
```

Not sure if it is the right approach. I wish to avoid putting nulls or stuff like that. I don't know if going the `Option` way is in some way better (if it works at all).

How is it best to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example:

```
sealed abstract class TermType
case class TermTypeSimple(name: String) extends TermType
case class TermTypeWithParen(name: String, parent: TermType) extends TermType
```

Other way:

```
case class TermType(name: String, superType: Option[TermType] = None)
```

With usages:

```
TermType("Hi")
TermType("Buy", Some(TermType("Beer"))
```

Comment: Thanks, the second case is much cleaner. Is it possible to have it defaulting to TermType("Object") in some way instead of None? but Object's superType needs to be None then.

Comment: Based on what you suggested, would something like this make sense? `case class TermType(name: String, superType: Option[TermType] = Some(TermType("Object", None)))`

Comment: I am personally see no benefits in making default None one step further in hierarchy, but might be your application needs to default on "complex" leaf nodes. It will be quite easy to change later if you will not be fully satisfied, so choose one approach and work on it :).

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to model the default hierarchy that any TermType of my DSL extends Object, irrespective of whether it is explicitly specified or not. Object obviously does not have any super type.